# Retrieve stored procedure definition from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT  
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id), 
    OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)
FROM 
    sys.procedures
WHERE 
    OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%xxxx%'
```

The above query displays the stored procedure definition, but the result is displayed in a single line. It is really hard to read.

I tried to change the display result by text. But it has max length limit 8000 char.

Is there any way I can query a readable stored procedure definition or any tool I can use to convert the single line stored procedure to a more readable script.

Comment: What database client?

Comment: Finally, I right click the result grid and save it as file. It solves my problem

Comment: it is sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can export the definition to file.
If you want to seach which procesures container some text, you can use red gate free tools [SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)

```
DECLARE @OLE            INT 
DECLARE @FileID         INT
DECLARE    @File VARCHAR(2000), @Text VARCHAR(max)


EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @OLE OUT 
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @File, 8, 1 
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @FileID, 'WriteLine', Null, @Text
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @FileID 
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @OLE
```